# Convert hash into SQL conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sanitization

I am in the process of upgrading my Rails app from 4.1.16 to 5.2.3.

I want to convert a hash into the string of SQL conditions( From `{ :name => "foo'bar", :group_id => 4 }` to `name='foobar' and group_id =4`) . It seems sanitize_sql_for_conditions has deprecated for hash conditions.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql_for_conditions({ :name => "foo'bar", :group_id => 4 })
```

returns `{:name=>"foobar", :group_id=>4}`

How can I convert the hash into the SQL condition?

Comment: You can invoke `sanitize_sql_for_conditions` right from the model, have you tried that?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Yes. I tried it from model and got the same result.

Comment: Tested on a fresh Rails 5.2.3, it returns `{:name=>"foo'bar", :group_id=>4}` isn't that what you want? no deprecation message.

Comment: Yes it returns hash as the result. But I want to convert this hash into SQL condition as a string like  name = 'foobar' and group_id = 4

Comment: That's going to work? Why do you need that format? Is it for a where clause?

Comment: Yes. It was for a where clause. I have an array of hash condition and want to join  these with OR. It was working fine in Rails 4

Comment: Maybe you can add more info to your question, so we can think in other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in method to produce a SQL query from a parameter hash but you can easily built it yourself with string literals, in your example that would be :

```
> h = { :name => "foo'bar", :group_id => 4 }
> h.map{ |el| "#{el.first}=#{el.last}" }.join(" AND ")
=> "name=foo'bar AND group_id=4"
```

Comment: This will not work for if one of the items is nil